# "No such file to load" error when running Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

```
Mac OS 10.4
rspec (1.1.11, 1.1.4, 1.1.3, 0.5.15)
rspec-rails (1.1.11)
rspec_generator (0.5.15)
rails 2.2.2
ruby 1.8.6 (2007-03-13 patchlevel 0) [universal-darwin8.0]
```

Created a new project...

```
$ rails myproject
```

Installed rspec into the project...

```
$ script/generate rspec
```

Generated a resource...

```
$ script/generate rspec_scaffold myresource name:string description:text
```

Tried to run specs...

```
$ rake spec
```

Got this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- ./spec/models/../../vendor/generators/rspec/lib/rspec_on_rails (MissingSourceFile)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:155:in `require'
        from ./spec/models/../spec_helper.rb:3
        from ./spec/models/entry_spec.rb:1:in `require'
        from ./spec/models/entry_spec.rb:1
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load_files'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:13:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:13:in `load_files'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:98:in `run_examples'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/command_line.rb:10:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/bin/spec:4
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- /Users/ethan/project/project/spec/../vendor/generators/rspec/lib/rspec_on_rails (MissingSourceFile)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:155:in `require'
        from /Users/ethan/project/project/spec/spec_helper.rb:3
            from ./spec/controllers/entries_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
        from ./spec/controllers/entries_controller_spec.rb:1
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load_files'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:13:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:13:in `load_files'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:98:in `run_examples'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/lib/spec/runner/command_line.rb:10:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.1.11/bin/spec:4
```

Indeed, there is no such file...

vendor/generators, ls:

```
rspec_controller        rspec_model
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to work for me.
I have installed *rspec-rails*, runned the rspec generator and when I give

```
$ script/generate
```

I get the list of generators:

> Installed Generators
>     Rubygems: rspec, rspec_controller, rspec_model, rspec_scaffold
>     Builtin: controller, integration_test, mailer, migration, model, observer, performance_test, plugin, resource, scaffold, session_migration

After generating the scaffold with *rspec_scaffold* the specs pass.
Are the vendor/generators in your rails project ? I think you should delete them and use the generators from the gems instead.

Comment: It fixed a problem i was having anyway.  For some reason rspec wasn't installed in a project I just started.  doh!   So thanks +1

Comment: I installed rspec gem but, I still get the error. Do you know the windows command for this ?

Answer (score 26):

For rails3

To get the list

```
$ rails generate
```

To generate spec_helper.rb

```
$ rails g rspec:install
```

Comment: how do I make this `rails g rspec:install` work on my windows 7 pc with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3?